# Can I re-download an audiobook that I purchased from iTunes again?

Tags: itunes, ios

Apps purchased from the app store and songs purchased from iTunes can be downloaded again by going to the purchased section in the respective app and clicking the cloud button.

Neither app shows the audio-books I have purchased and when I look at a specific book I have already purchased in the iTunes store it shows the buy button.

Will I get charged again if I click the buy button or will it just re-download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google shows various links that say that it is *not possible to automatically re-download Audio Books in iTunes*.

For example, this recent one - [previously purchased audiobooks not showing up](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3460435?start=0&tstart=0) -  from 3-Nov-2011:

> You only get one download of audiobooks and movies. It is your responsibility to backup your purchases.

Similarly:

- [Redownload Audio Book PLEASE!!!](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2730403?start=0&tstart=0)
- [iTunes Audiobook redownload](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=994901)

A few replies, like [this one](https://discussions.apple.com/message/12974570#12974570), include extra info:

- [How to back up your iTunes purchases](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1382) (though that Apple page says "This article has been archived and is no longer updated by Apple.")
- **[How to contact iTunes Support, to request the ability to re-download your purchase](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/)**

#### Conclusion

If you have any past back-ups of your desktop machine where you run iTunes and sync(ed) your device, you should be able to restore your purchase.

Otherwise, your best bet is to contact [iTunes Store support](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/).

Comment: I have heard from clients and end-users that iTunes Support can and will reset your "downloaded" flag on all of your purchases if you have a good reason, but they will do this only once. For example, if your house was burglarized and all of your computer equipment was stolen (including your Time Machine backups), they will let you re-download everything *once*. I do not know exactly what the standard is for a good-enough reason.

Comment: I will phone support, as my copy of Steve Jobs Biography (how ironic) does not work, hence why i want to re-download it.

Comment: You can redownload audiobooks from the iBooks app now https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201272

Answer (score 2):

Most of these older answers are incorrect now. In recent versions of iOS you can [re-download all your audiobooks purchased through iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201272) by starting the iBooks app, and going to the Purchased tab at the bottom right. From there you can choose what to redownload from My Purchases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using iBooks in your device?

If you have iOS5 installed you will be asked if you want to sync your books and files  on iCloud, say yes. Then go to the Book store ans navigate to purchased, rather than searching for the book.

If it is in this list you will be able to download it again, If it is not in the list, you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Audio books purchased through iTunes on any Mac or iOS devices cannot be redownloaded via iCloud because of, based on my understanding, licensing with Audible which is where all of the audio books on iTunes come from. Apple will regrant you the download if you somehow lost it, but in the future, if you often get audio books through iTunes, you may want to sync your iOS devices with your computer just for audio book purposes and make sure to use Time Machine or other methods to back up your computer. Movies, TV shows, apps, music, and books purchased from iBooks will redownload through iCloud - but not audio books or ring tones.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you got your audio books there are different ways to Sync Audiobooks in the Cloud. http://www.ifunia.com/blog/how-to-sync-audiobooks-in-the-cloud/

Comment: I dont't see how this would solve the problem stated in the question. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.